# Custom JSON marshaling for external packages

Tags: go

How can I add custom JSON marshaling to structs from external packages?  I am unable to add the `MarshalJSON` and `UnmarshalYAML` to these structs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add that struct to one defined by you. Then add the functions `MarshalJSON` and `UnmarshalYAML` to your struct:

```
type YourStruct struct {
    ImportedStruct
}

func (s *YourStruct) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that certainly works.  The annoying bit is that when I use `YourStruct` with "older" code, I have to pass `instance.ImportedStruct`.

Comment: Yeah, I know but this is how Go embedding works: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding